# Matrix ring over a semi-simple algebra

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules, semi-simple-rings

I'm working on the following question and I'm a little stuck.  Would appreciate any hints or solutions to any parts.

> Let $A$ be a finite-dimensional semi-simple algebra over $\mathbb{C}$
>   and set $M_n(A)$ to be the set of $n\times n$ matrices over $A$.
>
> 1. Show that $M_2(A)$ is semisimple
> 2. If $dim_{\mathbb{C}}(A)$ is prime, show that $M_2(A)$ is not simple
> 3. If $A$ is not commutative, there is a $t\in M_2(A)$ with $t^3\neq 0$ and $t^4=0$

Here are my thoughts.  For 1, we can first decompose $A$ into its product of simple pieces.  And if a module is simple over a field, is it isomorphic to the field itself?  So we can use this to get $M_2(A) = \oplus M_2(A_i)$ Where the $A_i$'s are the simple pieces. I feel like I'm close at this point, but how do I finish?

for part 2. I'm not sure how dim is defined here
for part 3.  This seems to have something to do with the fact that $M_2(A)$ has dimension 4.  I'm thinking something about annihilators and order of a module would be relevant here.

[Old Qualifying Exam Spring 1992](https://dornsife.usc.edu/assets/sites/990/docs/Pre_2012_papers/Algebra_Pre_2011.pdf)

Comment: The dimension is part 2 is probably just regular vector space dimension. The matrix ring is simple iff $A$ is, and $A$ is simple iff it’s a matrix ring over $\mathbb C$. That should be enough to do 2.  If $A$, you have that $A$ contains a nontrivial matrix ring, and I bet it’s not hard to concoct a matrices that become entries in a 2x2 matrix that have the properties you’re looking for.